# get matche string between two string or more php

Tags: php, string

i have two string as exmaple first one its

```
$str1 = "Hi stackoverflow community, I am new user and i have question, can you help me please";
$str2 = "Hi gamers community, I am new user and i have question, any one can help me please";
```

i want to extract all Sentence with more than (2) words and its

> community, I am new user and i have question,

AND

> help me please

so after search and make some code like made array and push to it similar word and word position and then compare the position of word but faced some issues so i do more search and found this method

```
function getLongestMatchingSubstring($str1, $str2)
{
    $len_1 = strlen($str1);
    $longest = '';
    $a = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $len_1; $i++){
        for($j = $len_1 - $i; $j > 0; $j--){
            $sub = substr($str1, $i, $j);
            if (strpos($str2, $sub) !== false && strlen($sub) > strlen($longest)){
                $longest = $sub;
                $a[] = $sub;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

i just edit little for made it return array of matched string but its have two issuse first one
its didn't extract all matched string becaue of the condition

and result its

```
0 => string 'i ' (length=2)
1 => string ' community, I am new user and i have question, ' (length=47)
```

> we can see `can you help me please` not exist in result because of the if statment `strlen($sub) > strlen($longest)`

i tried to edit the if statment but faild its start giving me horrible result like

```
0 => string ' community, I am new user and i have question, ' (length=47)
  1 => string 'community, I am new user and i have question, ' (length=46)
  2 => string ' I am new user and i have question, ' (length=36)
  3 => string 'I am new user and i have question, ' (length=35)
  4 => string ' am new user and i have question, ' (length=34)
  5 => string 'am new user and i have question, ' (length=33)
  6 => string ' new user and i have question, ' (length=31)
  7 => string 'new user and i have question, ' (length=30)
  8 => string ' user and i have question, ' (length=27)
  9 => string 'user and i have question, ' (length=26)
  10 => string ' and i have question, ' (length=22)
  11 => string 'and i have question, ' (length=21)
  12 => string ' i have question, ' (length=18)
  13 => string 'i have question, ' (length=17)
  14 => string ' have question, ' (length=16)
  15 => string 'have question, ' (length=15)
```

and the second issue its take long time

so any logarithm fordo this job ? or and idea for make some edit of the if statement

Comment: Perhaps give example input and wanted output.  I'm not quite following what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Progrock find matches between two string that's all

Answer (score 0):

I am reading your question as given a needle of more than two words find the sentence that contains them, please correct me if I misunderstood.

```
<?php

$sentences =
[
    'I like my rubber ducky.',
    'Paperclips make me happy, I have lots.'
];

$needle = 'make me happy';

foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
    if(strpos($sentence, $needle) !== false) {
        echo $sentence;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Paperclips make me happy, I have lots.
```

Comment: without `$needle` just two string compare and find matches

Comment: @dailytube, so given: `space is big, really big, you just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big it is.`  and the strings `really big` and `how vastly`, should it return: `,you just won't believe `?  What do you mean by matches?